# Spark Job is stuck at SUBMITTED when set Driver Memory > 5 GB

Tags: java, apache-spark

I'm working on Spark with Standalone Cluster mode. I need to increase the Driver Memory as I got OOM in t he driver thread. If found that when setting  the Driver Memory to > 5 GB, the submitted job is stuck at Submitted in the driver and the application never starts.
I have 64 GB Memory in my machine and 16 Cores.
I set the driver memory in spark-default.conf

Comment: I found this happens when setting the driver memory much than the executor's one. But still can't understand what is the relation between them !

Answer (score 0):

from Spark Master UI, the driver should be executed in one of the Executors. That's why its memory shouldn't exceed the Executors memory.